# Evaluating a contour integral using Cauchy's generalised integral formula

Tags: contour-integration, cauchy-integral-formula

**Exercise:** Evaluate the following integral using the Cauchy Integral Formula (the contour is traversed once anti-clockwise):

$$ \int_{|z| = 2} \frac{(z^2 + 1)}{(z - 3) (z^2 - 1)} dz $$

I found the singularities as being:

$$z=3\; and\; z = \pm 1$$

I then plotted these points and the contour on the argand diagram and then rewrote the integral as:

$$ \int_{|z| = 2} \frac{\frac{(z^2 + 1)}{(z - 3)}}{(z^2 - 1)} dz $$

because the singularity $z = 3$ is outside the contour $|z| = 2$ and to use Cauchy's generalised integral formula $f(z)$ must not have any singularities within the contour on the plane.

At this point I can't just immediately use the formula because of the form of the denominator. Expanding it into $ (z - 1) (z + 1) $ doesn't satisfy the formula either. $(z - 1) (z + 1)$ != $(z - w)^{n-1}$.

How do I evaluate this integral?

Comment: Are you sure they didn't mean using Cauchy's residue theorem?

Comment: Yeah, this question was under the section "Cauchy's integral formula". The residue related theorem is presented later in the lecture notes.

Comment: Yeah, I usually think of the integral formula as only handling one singularity at a time. So I guess what you could do is rewrite the contour so that it consists of a contour going around $+1$ and another contour going around $-1.$ This is kind of moving towards just proving the residue theorem, but it'll work.

Comment: Did you not see how my hint lets you use cauchy integral formula directly? Just write $ \frac{1}{z^2-1} = \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{z+1}-\frac{1}{z-1}\right)$ and then you can split the integral into two integrals each of which only has one singularity.

Comment: Maybe my algebra is poor but I got a different (incorrect) answer when I substituted that in. I found the other answer easier to follow.

Comment: Well do you disagree with the identity (the correct version in the answer not the off-by-a-minus-sign one in the comment)? Certainly that's not what's wrong, it's just partial fractions. (FWIW I get $-i\pi/2$ using it). Anyway, not about the checkmark, I just wanted to make sure you saw (especially since based on your comment I wasn't sure you actually grasped the thing about rewriting the contour).

Comment: Yeah, it makes sense now. I also got the correct solution using the method you suggested (using the correct version in your answer). I'll keep this in mind when solving these types of problems in future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:**
\begin{align}
\dfrac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{|z| = 2} \frac{\frac{(z^2 + 1)}{(z - 3)}}{(z^2 - 1)} dz  &=\dfrac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{C_1} \frac{\frac{(z^2 + 1)}{(z - 3)(z-1)}}{(z + 1)^1} dz +\dfrac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{C_2} \frac{\frac{(z^2 + 1)}{(z - 3)(z+1)}}{(z - 1)^1} dz \\
&=\dfrac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{C_1} \frac{f_1}{(z + 1)^1} dz +\dfrac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{C_2} \frac{f_2}{(z - 1)^1} dz
\end{align}
where $f_1$ ad $f_2$ are analytic over $C_1$ and $C_2$ respectively.

[image]

Comment: Why can you break the integral into different parts?

Comment: You can break an integral into different parts about every singularity over a simple connected domain with your contour!.

Comment: Is there a theorem that I can use to support this? I showed my professor that solution for feedback and he said that I can't continue using the integral formula after breaking the integral into two pieces because f(z) won't be holomorphic because of the singularity being in the numerator. Personally, I can see that you're redefining the contour (so f(z) in those cases are actually holomorphic and satisfy the integral formula) for each integral but could you point me to something I can use to rationalise that decision?

Comment: Can you redefine the contour for each integral and make $C_1$ and $C_2$ about $z=-1$ and $z=1$.?

Comment: @user486323 In $|z|<2$ the function is holomorphic except in points $z=\pm1$ so in this circle except in a very small neighborhood about these points we have $\int_{C-{(C_1\cup C_2)}}f=0$ so $\int_{C}f=\int_{C_1\cup C_2}f$.

Comment: For theorem see https://books.google.com/books?id=GXQQRYUc7gQC&lpg=PA223&ots=h8pGDfMm47&dq=We%20indicate%20a%20method%20of%20proof%20that%20involves%20%22transforming%22%20a%20multiply&pg=PA224#v=onepage&q=

Comment: Thanks! After discussing it with him and explaining it further it is something that's permitted. Thank you for the solution and explanation.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

The best way to do this is to probably use the Residue theorem, or rewrite the contour so that it goes around $z=1$ and $z=-1$ separately (thus "moving toward" the residue theorem). However, here's a trick that will let you use only the Cauchy integral formula without modifying the contour: $$ \frac{1}{z^2-1} = \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{z-1} - \frac{1}{z+1}\right) $$